# Xcode automatically builds test target as a part of iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing a React Native mobile app for iOS. I had an error that was caused by the Tests target, but I spent 2 days trying to "fix" my main target before I discovered the problem in the Tests target.

To solve this, I would like to be able to build, debug, and deploy my app without bundling it with the "Tests" target.  In other words I want to deal with them separately so I don't have to fix bugs in the Tests target before I can run my app on a device, or deploy it.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you get the problem when build the app in Xcode using the `Product  > Build For > Running`? Because it should build without the test part.

Comment: The issue doesn't occur at compile time.  It happens after the app is built and signed and after attempting to run on a device.  This also happens when I try to deploy to test flight.  That said, to answer your question, no I'm able to build successfully.  I'm also able to debug on the simulator.  I discovered the issue when I tried to test the camera functionality on my app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your build scheme, make sure that the test target is checked only for "Test" in the "Build tab"

[image: Check Here]